# Is there some way to "trick" an individual PHP script into thinking that the system clock/date is something other than what it actually is?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, clock

I need to debug all kinds of time-related issues. One bug only happens for one hour every six months. It's tedious to wait half a year for a one-hour window to fix this bug. Due to this, and similar test situations, I would like to "fake the system clock/date" for an individual PHP script.

It must not change the actual system clock/date! Actually changing that would be catastrophic for all kinds of logs I keep, no matter how briefly.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
set_fake_time_for_this_script('1995-05-04 04:24:15');
sleep(3);
var_dump(time()); // Will not return the timestamp for my computer's system clock, but instead "1995-05-04 04:24:18".
// Any other time-related functions will also use that fake time/date as the "present time".
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Please tell me it is...

Answer (score 1):

This is **not possible** the way PHP implements the time functionality.

PHP reads the time from the server it's hosted on(in your case, can be your pc) and therefore you cannot change the time just like that.

There however is a clever method of doing what you need. Since time is just a timestamp at its core, and that's a number, find the difference (positive or negative) of timestamp between the current time and the time you want to set in your function. You will get an offset.

Then perform all computation that you want to do with time, and add the offset to that. This way you will get all functionality of time without implementing the whole time functions again.

```
function mytime() {
    return time()+set_mytime();
}

function set_mytime($new_time=null) {
    static $offset;
    if(!$new_time) {return $offset;}
    //$new_time should be a unix timestamp as generated by time(), mktime() or strtotime(), etc
    $real_time=time();
    $offset=$real_time-$new_time;
}
```

Also, if you are very much interested in changing the time, you can use the `exec` function and call the system commands to do that. However please note that changing time for entire system randomly will have unexpected results.

Comment: But I rarely use time()... So I'd have to figure out how (if possible at all) to send a "custom time" anywhere a time is sent. Which varies between each time-related function, if it even has one at all...

Comment: are you performing any computation on this time ?